# How can I prevent MSVC from deleting unused strings?

Tags: c, visual-c++

MSVC will remove unused `char*` strings from compiled executables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* test = "Hey, I'm a string.";
char* test2 = "I'm yet another string.";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    puts("test123");
    puts(test2);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

IDA string list:

[image]

What can I do to force MSVC to leave these strings in the `.exe`?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not trying to solve a specific problem; this question has been asked out of curiosity and to help me with testing, but there's no particular issue behind it.

Comment: What options are you passing to the compiler?  I'm fairly certain that all of the strings should be in the resulting binary so long as you aren't passing `/Gw`.  Without `/Gw`, both `test1` and `test2` will be dragged into the link by `main`.

Comment: Marking as volatile will also prevent optimizer from interfering with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [linker /OPT option documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx):

> **/OPT:NOREF** keeps functions and data that are never referenced.

If you only want to keep specific data, then use [/INCLUDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs.aspx): `/INCLUDE:test`.